# Return statement takes long (no computation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have encountered a confusing problem

I have fetching some records, and recursively selected their self associated records. This is fairly quick, but when I return the data, even after all the computations/filtering has been done, the return statement hangs for like a second before returning the result

```
  # recursively looks for succesful carrier product price on owner carrier products
  #
  def referenced_carrier_product_price
    start = Time.now
    puts "start"
    ancestors = CarrierProduct.find_carrier_product_ancestors(carrier_product_id: self.id).includes(:carrier_product_price).references(:carrier_product_price)
    puts "ancestors #{Time.now - start}"

    parent    = ancestors.select{ |cp| cp.id == self.carrier_product_id }.first
    puts "parent #{Time.now - start}"

    until parent.nil? || ancestors.empty?
      puts "check #{Time.now - start}"
      is_successful = parent.carrier_product_price.try('successful?')
      puts "is_successful #{Time.now - start}"
      price = parent.carrier_product_price
      puts "price #{Time.now - start}"

      return price if is_successful
      puts "CCP #{Time.now - start}"
      parent = ancestors.select{ |cp| cp.id == parent.carrier_product_id }.first
      puts "Loop parent #{Time.now - start}"
    end
    return
  end
```

Below I show the output to console

```
parent 0.003545
check 0.003572
is_successful 0.003609
price 0.003621

... 1 second later
=> #<CarrierProductPrice....
```

As you can see, all the computation is completed at 0.003621, yet i still get the result a second later

PS. this record stores a fairly large serialised field which may be the cause?

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are doing this in IRB. IRB has to call `.inspect` on the result to print it out, and in this case it is probably taking a while to do the inspect on a large field, and it takes a while to write it to the console.

Comment: Worth noting that this can be actually avoided with `referenced_carrier_product_price and nil` - inspect will be called on the nil object instead.

Comment: `res = referenced_carrier_product_price;` works as well. The semi-colon causes it to return nil as it is a new (empty) expression.